# Android notification click to open app only works 1st time

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a foreground service with a notification. I create the notification like this:

```
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("App name")
            .setContentText(Utility.getNotificationContentText())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .build();
```

On the notification I set a pending intent like so:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

When I click the notification the **first time**, it works as expected. It opens the app. However, when I **click the notification the second time, nothing happens.**

For what it's worth, I open the MainActivity.class, but my app has different fragments. I would like to open a specific fragment, but I am not sure if I can pass FragmentName.class into the intent.

**Any help for getting the notification click to work every time?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. The problem was that I was updating the notification with a intent that had the wrong class.

Answer (score 1):

Set the below flags of the `PendingIntet` so that you can update if there is a current pending intent with the new `PendingIntent`.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 
              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work.